# Angular method returning unrendered code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some angular partials that seem to render properly in the DOM:

```
 <button ng-click="doThisThing('{{ item.id }}')">
```

Renders into this:

```
<button ng-click="doThisThing('1234')">
```

And my method in my controller:

```
$scope.doThisThing = function(id) { console.log(id) }
```

Outputs this:

```
{{ item.id }}
```

Why isn't my function receiving the proper id?

Comment: try "doThisThing(item.id)"

Comment: Yeah, that did it. Thanks! I tried this previous and was met with grievous errors. Guess I tried it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not use `{{}}` inside `ng-click`. Just like `ng-if`, `ng-click` just takes the arguments as such and It will evaluate it and no need to do data binding as in `{{}}`.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qirawo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

```
 <button ng-click="doThisThing(item.id)">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
<button ng-click="doThisThing(item.id)">
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 <button ng-click="doThisThing(item.id)">
```